# Converting RIJNDAEL 256 function from .Net to Python

Tags: python, vb.net, encryption, rijndael

Can someone please help me with converting this code?

I tried to make RIJNDAEL256 function out of this code:

```vb
EncryptRJ256("lkirwf897+22#bbtrm8814z5qq=498j5", "741952hheeyy66#cs!9hjv887mxx7@8y", "A padded string to BLOCKSIZE length.")

Public Function EncryptRJ256(ByVal prm_key As String, ByVal prm_iv As String, ByVal prm_text_to_encrypt As String) As String
    Dim s As String = prm_text_to_encrypt
    Dim managed2 As New RijndaelManaged With {
    .Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros,
    .Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
    .BlockSize = 256
}
    Dim stream As New MemoryStream
    Dim stream2 As New CryptoStream(stream, managed2.CreateEncryptor(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(prm_key), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(prm_iv)), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s)
    stream2.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    stream2.FlushFinalBlock()
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray)
End Function
```

I need the output of the encrypted string to be something like this:

```
Dv0Y/AFXdFMlDrcldFCu8v5o9zAlLNgyM+vO+PFeSrpO8Ve82mdUcc4rkzp9afDYc75NmkSd4mdflt38kceOdA==

A padded string to BLOCKSIZE length
```

I came up with this but the output is invalid. It's probably because of wrong padding but I have no idea how to fix it:

```python
from rijndael.cipher.crypt import new
from rijndael.cipher.blockcipher import MODE_CBC
import base64

PADDING = b'.'

def r_pad(payload, block_size=32):
    return payload + (block_size - len(payload) % block_size) * PADDING

KEY = 'lkirwf897+22#bbtrm8814z5qq=498j5'
IV = '741952hheeyy66#cs!9hjv887mxx7@8y'
plain_text = "A padded string to BLOCKSIZE length."

rjn = new(KEY, MODE_CBC, IV, blocksize=32)
encd = rjn.encrypt(r_pad(plain_text))
data = base64.b64encode(encd)
print(data)

rjn = new(KEY, MODE_CBC, IV, blocksize=32)
data = base64.b64decode(data)
decd = rjn.decrypt(r_pad(data))
print (decd)
```

This is the output:

```
Dv0Y/AFXdFMlDrcldFCu8v5o9zAlLNgyM+vO+PFeSrqWdzP1S1cumviFiEjNAjz5njnMMC9lfxsBl71x5y+xCw==

A padded string to BLOCKSIZE length.............................Å¿:è°⌐┘n┤«╞Px╜:æC┬♣╬Q┤▼«U_♦â☻ìr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How silly of me! Here's what fixed my issue:

```
from rijndael.cipher.crypt import new
from rijndael.cipher.blockcipher import MODE_CBC
import base64

PADDING = b'\x00'

def pad(payload, block_size=32):
    return payload + (block_size - len(payload) % block_size) * PADDING

def un_pad(payload):
    return payload.replace(PADDING, '')

KEY = 'lkirwf897+22#bbtrm8814z5qq=498j5'
IV = '741952hheeyy66#cs!9hjv887mxx7@8y'
plain_text = "A padded string to BLOCKSIZE length."

rjn = new(KEY, MODE_CBC, IV, blocksize=32)
encd = rjn.encrypt(pad(plain_text))
data = base64.b64encode(encd)
print(data)

rjn = new(KEY, MODE_CBC, IV, blocksize=32)
data = base64.b64decode(data)
decd = rjn.decrypt(un_pad(data))
print (decd)
```